# Entropy lower bound

Tags: expectation, information-theory, entropy

I have the following observation:
$$Z=\sqrt{P}H+W,$$
where
$$H \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma^2). $$
$P$ is given and fixed. I am trying to find $W$ that minimizes $h(Z)$. Given that $E[|W|^2]=\sqrt{\Gamma}$, one case is when $\Gamma\geq P$ we can use $W=kH$ and $k=-\sqrt{P}$. What I am struggling with is how to find the optimal $W$ that minizes $Z$ for the case when $P>\Gamma$.

Comment: What follows "In other words..." is not clear at all for me. Why "$W$ that minimizes $Z$"? Why $Z$ and $Z_A$ ? Why the condition on $H$ alone ? Please elaborate

Comment: Thanks, I had a second thought on the problem and rewrite it.

Comment: Again: what do you mean by "minimize $Z$"? You mean its entropy? Further, $H$ and $W$ are (possibly correlated) random variables, no? $P$ is a given fixed number? (it so, it looks strange that you didn't place into $\sigma^2$, perhaps you meant that $\sigma^2=1$?)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find $W$ that minimizes the entropy of $Z$ and yes, unfortunately they are correlated.